# In Star Trek DS9, how do changelings reproduce?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

We know that DS9 Changelings. Odo's species, reproduce because Odo himself was found as a "baby" and he was told by the founder that they had sent him and other babies out into space, but I don't recall any mention of how babies are made. I know they join with one another or in the great link in a liquid form, but that doesn't seem to be a matter of reproduction since their gender doesn't seem to matter in linking. We also know that Odo introduced the female founder to physical sex that solids enjoy, but by what process do changelings actually reproduce?

Comment: They reproduce off-screen.

Comment: http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/How_do_Changelings_reproduce

Comment: The ocean becomes a drop

Comment: With Bajoran females.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make some assumptions, they are all based on "the link" which allows for them all to become one, yet retain their individuality. In theory, to develop a separate consciousness they would have to separate a small amount of the material from the link, enough for the separate material to be sentient, but not enough for it to have developed it's own specific consciousness. In theory, based on the fact that individual changelings can develop independently, they would start developing their own consciousness, and subsequently their own personality based on their actions and experiences. This can be partially proved by the learning process Odo went through when he was on Bajor, as he was experimented on he learned how to interact with his environment, and eventually take corporeal form, learning everything he knew from the scientist he was with.